# Trying to understand Unreal Engine 4 replication

Tags: unreal-engine4, multiplayer, unreal-blueprint

I'm trying to understand how to call events between client and server. My goal for now is simple. I want to create anything that is interactable for 2 players.

Easiest thing I could think of was cube that is switching color when clicked. So I did create actor based blueprint, checked "Replicates" and AlwaysRelevant to be sure. PlayerController is also replicated and there is no pawn needed.

Color change blueprint:
[image: Color change blueprint]

SM is just static mesh if that is important. As far as I know client have no authority to call multicast events so I wanted to push it through server but it stops there. Called from server works as expected and color itself IS replicated to client, however client cannot change color himself.

What am I missing in this concept? I've watched like 5 videos about replication and I started to think there is something missing which is either obvious for everyone but me or their examples do not need things I do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found out, a player's client can not directly call server RPCs on actors which the player does not *own*. Calls must be routed through that player's PlayerController. The server copy of the player's PlayerController can then call server methods on server-owned actors.

Another issue is that you seem to be using both RPCs and replicated properties for the same purpose. Unclear to me why `changed` is replicated since you're modifying it in a multicast event which normally runs on all the machines. This is a recipe for hard to find race condition bugs.

Replication in Unreal is definitely one of the harder concepts to get the hang of. The resource that helped me the most is [this guide](https://cedric-neukirchen.net/Downloads/Compendium/UE4_Network_Compendium_by_Cedric_eXi_Neukirchen.pdf) which while quite dated, is both comprehensive and to the point.

Comment: This is the piece i was missing in all of this. Probably because all tutorials I've seen have been about replicating pawns and assigned actors like weapons. 
Variable is replicated only because it was trial and error since I couldn't find solution. It will be turned back off. Thank you for pointing that out.
Glad to have this guide, will surely get into it. That answers my question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have it in PlayerController, it's got to be in a Pawn, or if not, in PlayerState, or it won't get shared to other clients.